# JSTL: accessing the second xml dom variable in a <x:forEach>

Tags: xml, xpath, jstl

I'm trying to access a second xmldom in a  loop.

```
<c:import var="some1xml" url="/xml/some1.xml"/>
<c:import var="some2xml" url="/xml/some2.xml"/>
<x:parse xml="${some1xml}" var="some1"/>
<x:parse xml="${some2xml}" var="some2"/>

<x:forEach select="$some1xml/config/seats/seat[@id > $Start and @id < $End]" var="seats">
    <x:out select="$some2xml/root/name[@id='$seats/@id']"/>
</x:forEach>
```

But it won't return me anything. Not even when I remove the xpath condition.
When I place it above the forEach it does return me data so the parse is succesfull.

What could be wrong or is this normal behaviour in JSTL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the second xml document. The document had a documentRoot called root. Which confused the taglibrary. Removing the root in the xPath did the trick.